# Bad perfomance on Ubuntu server 22.04 wit zpool on mirror zfs

Tags: server, zfs, 22.04

have a HP miniserver Gen 8 with 3T mirror zpool with zfs. Installed Ubuntu server 22.04 and notice a remarkable lower performance. CPU activity is between 50-100% as soon as there is any activity on the zpool. Seems like there is some performance penalty on this configuration in Ubuntu 22.04 server. Any suggestions for performance improvement.
One notice: zpool was not installed default with features without had to be added manual with >sudo zpool upgrade . Are there more parameters that has to be adjusted manually?

Update 2022-06-12
No problem with zpool status for sure!
Cant find any issues with dmesg -T

The server is a pure backup server.
Today the only thing the server was doing was receiving a container from my online server (lxc copy command from online server to this backup server)
Throughput was first part 5MB/s but then after some hours only some 100KB/s! top command gave that the CPU was 100% occupied with 98.6 wa (waiting for I/O)
So there is some fatal problem with performance with the mirrored zfs zpool!
How to find out what is the problem?
Why is the CPU completely occupied waiting for I/O?
any suggestions?

Comment: How many connections do you have? Are you sharing Volumes via ISCSI? Is the Pool healthy? ```zpool status``` Do you have IO error messages in the Kernel logs? ```dmesg -T```

Comment: I also upgraded two servers (one HP Microserver Gen8 and one Dell T140) from 18.04 to 22.04, and the performance of the 4-disk raidz2 pools on both of them is now **painfully** slow — **way** worse than it was with 18.04, even without any encryption, and with a 1TB Samsung 970 NVMe L2ARC attached to one of the servers.  If you get any clue on why that is, please share.